# Select all data from table a per data in table b

Tags: mysql

In my table a:

```
id   |    name
1    |    Raid
2    |    Surrender
```

In my table b:

```
id   |    code
1    |    nlc
2    |    wlc
```

Desired output:

```
name      |    code
Raid      |    nlc
Raid      |    wlc
Surrender |    nlc
Surrender |    wlc
```

I tried:

```
SELECT name, "code" FROM table a
UNION ALL
SELECT "", code FROM table b
```

But the output is:

```
name      |     code
Raid      |     code
Surrender |     code
          |     nlc
          |     wlc
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the cross join that will return your desired result as below:

```
select a.name,b.code from a cross join b;
```

Comment: Thanks! You're brilliant. How does cross join works?

Comment: in your case you have "2" rows in both of table so the output will be 2*2=4 records.

Comment: If the information is useful to you, then you can upvote and answer it.

Comment: Yes, I will later, it has restriction of 10 minutes to accept answer. Thank again.